# R plotly add a image in background

Tags: r, image, plot, plotly

I try to use the "plotly" R package to plot an image in an R graphic.

I first tried to include an image from a local computer:

```
library(plotly)

outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")

png(outfile)
plot(rnorm(200), rnorm(200))
dev.off()

plot_ly(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3)) %>%
  layout(
    images = list(
      list(
        source =  outfile,
        xref = "x",
        yref = "y",
        x = 1,
        y = 1,
        sizex = 2,
        sizey = 2,
        sizing = "stretch",
        opacity = 0.4,
        layer = "below"
      )


    )
  )
```

But I did not manage to do it. I then thought that was because plotly apparently requires an http or https image.

First question: Is it possible to import image from a local file (apparently it is possible with python: https://plot.ly/python/images/)?

As it seems to be impossible to embed a local image, I try to import an image that I had upload on my Github. But it seems not to work neither:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3)) %>%
  layout(
    images = list(
      list(
        source =  "https://github.com/charlottesirot/elementR/blob/master/inst/www/2.png",
        xref = "x",
        yref = "y",
        x = 1,
        y = 1,
        sizex = 2,
        sizey = 2,
        sizing = "stretch",
        opacity = 0.4,
        layer = "below"
      )


    )
  )
```

What is the problem here?

I have looked everywhere, posted questions on plotly forum (http://community.plot.ly/t/import-a-local-image-in-plot/2476, http://community.plot.ly/t/add-a-background-image/2457) but I did not find my answers.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you see this https://plot.ly/~as5165/12/#code. Not R but may help. Image is base64. Let us know how you get on

Answer (score 7):

Two small things which needed to be changed.

- The URL pointed to something which looked like an image but actually shows the whole GitHub page, appending `?raw=true` makes sure that only the image is shown
- After loading the image the coordinates were outside the plot

Saving this code via htmlwidget still does not show the image because of some [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue. In the second snippet the image is `base64` encoded and added to the plot. It doesn't show in RStudio but in the HTML output.

The code below produces the following plot.

[image]

```
library('plotly')

plot_ly(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3), type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>%
  layout(
    images = list(
      list(
        source =  "https://github.com/charlottesirot/elementR/blob/master/inst/www/2.png?raw=true",
        xref = "x",
        yref = "y",
        x = 1,
        y = 3,
        sizex = 2,
        sizey = 2,
        sizing = "stretch",
        opacity = 0.4,
        layer = "below"
      )
    )
  )
```

---

Snippet for base64 encoded image.

```
library('plotly')
library('htmlwidgets')
library('RCurl')

image_file <- "/temp/2.png"
txt <- RCurl::base64Encode(readBin(image_file, "raw", file.info(image_file)[1, "size"]), "txt")


p <- plot_ly(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3), type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>%
  layout(
    images = list(
      list(
        source =  paste('data:image/png;base64', txt, sep=','),
        xref = "x",
        yref = "y",
        x = 1,
        y = 3,
        sizex = 2,
        sizey = 2,
        sizing = "stretch",
        opacity = 0.4,
        layer = "below"
      )
    )
  )
p
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, "/tmp/plot.html")
```